# How to call Array name with a string in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
const EleList = [1,2,3]
name = 'Ele'

const render = function(type){
    window[type + 'List'].forEach(function(value){
    console.log("LOL")


render('Ele')
```

What am i supposed to replace the window[name + 'List'] with to call an array using strings.

Comment: I don't know if we'll be able to answer that without knowing what the context is in which this code exists. That said, dynamic variable names are often a bit of a smell... I'd be curious as to your end-goal here.

Comment: `var arr = window[name + 'List']; arr.forEach((value)=> { ... })`

Comment: try this Try this

`window['name{list}']`

Comment: But, why would you want to pollute the global object? I would suggest you to simply use an object if you can.

Comment: Something along the lines of [this example](https://runkit.com/cms/5da729fbfc8b010013f8a971) would be better IMHO than using `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` or `let` variables are not added to the global `window` object.

Replacing `const` with `var` should solve your problem.

`var EleList = [1,2,3]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

> Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

> Just like const the let does not create properties of the window object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).

Comment: @Rubaninferno You are welcome. It is a bit of a weird spec decision that `var` adds the variable to the `window`, but `const` or `let` do not. If the answer solved your issue you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon.